# How to define template match in XSL transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried to generate my XSL file into a HTML format but it doesn't work. I think the issue comes from the template matches that I defined.

Here is the XML from what I built the template matches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISSO−8859−15" ?> 
<Library>
   <authors>
     <Author id="author1" name="Einstein"/>
   </authors> 
   <publications>
     <Book year="1900" title="7 Kingdoms" author="author1"/>
     <Magazine year="2010" number="203" title="The News"'/> 
     <Book year="1956" title="The Fall" author="author1"/>
   </publications> 
</Library>
```

Here is the HTML format that I want to get to **display the authors, books and publications**:

```
<html> 
   <h1>Library</h1> 
   <h2>Authors</h2> 
   <ul>
      <li id="author1">Einstein</li> 
   </ul>
   <h2>Books</h2> 
   <ul>
      <li>7 Kingdoms, 1942, <a href="#author">Einstein</a></li>
      <li>The Fall, 1956, <a href="#author">Einstein</a></li> 
   </ul>
   <h2>Magazines</h2> <ul>
      <li>The News (203), 2010</li> 
   </ul>
 </html>
```

And here are the template matches that I built:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="html"/>

 <xsl:template match="Author">
    <li id= "library/author/Author/@id">
        <xsl:value-of select="library/authors/Author/name"/>    
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Magazines">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="library/publications/magazine[@title]"/>
        (
        <xsl:value-of select="library/publications/magazine[@number]"/>
        ),
        <xsl:value-of select="library/publications/magazine[@year]"/> 

    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="library/publications/book[@year]"/>
        ,
        <xsl:value-of select="library/publications/book[@title]"/>
        ,
        <xsl:value-of select="library/publications/book/author/@ref"/>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As said earlier, I think the issue comes from the template matches which prevent to populate the HTML file properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An example should come **in addition to** an explanation of the logic required by the transformation - not **instead of** it.

Comment: You need to understand that relative path expressions like library/publications/book make selections *starting at the context item*, that is, the element that the template rule matches. All your selections appear to be starting at the root.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess (!), you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="author" match="Author" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/Library">
    <html> 
        <h1>Library</h1> 
        <h2>Authors</h2>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="authors/Author"/>
        </ul>
        <h2>Books</h2> 
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="publications/Book"/>
        </ul>
        <h2>Magazines</h2>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="publications/Magazine"/>
        </ul>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Author">
    <li id="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>    
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>    
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <a href="#author">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('author', @author)/@name"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Magazine">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
        <xsl:text>), </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example (after removing the extra apostrophe in line #7), the result will be:

```
<html>
   <h1>Library</h1>
   <h2>Authors</h2>
   <ul>
      <li id="author1">Einstein</li>
   </ul>
   <h2>Books</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>7 Kingdoms, 1900, <a href="#author">Einstein</a></li>
      <li>The Fall, 1956, <a href="#author">Einstein</a></li>
   </ul>
   <h2>Magazines</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>The News(203), 2010</li>
   </ul>
</html>
```